# Cmake package not found

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I've installed Drogon using vcpkg, and in my IDE I have following error:
`Package 'Drogon' not found. After installing, regenerate the CMake cache.`

I am using Visual Studio 2022

vcpkg_rf.txt:

```
install
drogon
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Drogon Server1")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Drogon Server1")

# Line below is showing the error
find_package(Drogon CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries("Drogon Server1" PRIVATE Drogon::Drogon)
```

I have found this error also:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/Documents/sdk/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:829 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Drogon" with any
  of the following names:

    DrogonConfig.cmake
    drogon-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Drogon" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Drogon_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Drogon"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: Did you use the vcpkg toolchain file when you configured your package on the command line? Or are you using a CMakeSettings.json file configured with the toolchain: [https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/)

Comment: I have configured vcpkg toolchain in CMakePresets.json.

Comment: like this: `"CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/Documents/sdk/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"`

Comment: I do have a complaint `project ("Drogon Server1")` and `add_subdirectory ("Drogon Server1")` you should avoid spaces in both of these.

Comment: Is there more info in the error message? I use vcpkg + Visual Studio + CMake but don't use the integration in the IDE. I use the standalone CMake-GUI to configure and generate my VS project. In CMake-GUI it should give you a longer error message when it cant find a package. It should mention that there are 2 files that it searched for but did not find and give the file names. If you see that check if either of these exist.

Comment: Assuming you create the target `"Drogon Server1"` in your `add_subdirectory` CMakeLists.txt you need to properly enclose it in quotes in your `target_link_libraries` command.  Try to avoid spaces in target names!

Comment: @vre I added quotes around it and it still gives me this error. (I have done this: `target_link_libraries("Drogon Server1" PRIVATE Drogon::Drogon)`)

Comment: @drescherjm I have added error it gives me at the end of question

Comment: Does your directory `C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/Documents/sdk/vcpkg` contains any Drogon files? `dir /r /s Drogon*` should show the files.

Comment: @vre Yes it does, it is saying: `Total files listed: 57 File(s)`

Comment: And are those `.cmake` files in question amongst them? How are they named?

Comment: @vre I can see some: `DrogonUtilities.cmake`, `DrogonConfig.cmake.in`, `DrogonConfigVersion.cmake`, `DrogonConfig.cmake`, `DrogonTargets.cmake`, `DrogonTargets-debug.cmake`, `DrogonTargets.cmake`, `DrogonTargets-release.cmake`, ...

Comment: Did you cleared the CMake cache as suggested, i.e. deleted CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles in the build directory or started in a fresh build directory after installation of drogon?

Comment: @vre I did, I have deleted whole build directory, I have even created another CMake project without spaces in the name, and it is still showing this error

Comment: There should be an entry in your CMakePresets.json file named `cacheVariables`. Please add a variable `Drogon_DIR` to it with the path to the `DrogonConfig.cmake` file, e.g.     `"cacheVariables": {
        "Drogon_DIR": "<path_to_DrogonConfig.cmake>"
      },` and retry in a new builddir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the given information:

> Visual Studio 2022

-> Means CMake will default to x64 -> vcpkg will use `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows`

> vcpkg_rf.txt: install drogon

-> Means you use a response file to install drogon. Without specifying the triplet this is `x86-windows`

As such your triplet used by CMake and vcpkg doesn't agree. Consider using vcpkg in manifest mode by providing a `vcpkg.json` with the dependency instead of a response file. This way you won't have a discrepancy in your triplet selection

(As always chanigng this also requires to delete the cmake cache for a clean reconfigure. Furthermore don't have spaces in your target and paths; you are just asking for trouble.)